# cd argument made of variable made of variable

Tags: bash, variables, cd

I have a variable that contain a path. Particularly, I need that this variable read the path from a second file (input). That why I am using awk. Variable is  something like this:

```
path_dock1=`awk 'NR==33 {print $1}' input`
```

In addition to path_dock1, there are other path_dock variable that are declared in the same way.

```
path_dock1=`awk 'NR==33 {print $1}' input`
path_dock2=`awk 'NR==34 {print $1}' input`
path_dock3=`awk 'NR==35 {print $1}' input`
...
```

I would like that such variable were used in a for loop. Particularly, I want to use this variable as argument of cd command. To do this, I am using a for loop variable that runs from 1 to n, where n is total number of path_dock 
variables.

```
for t in $(seq 1 1000)
do
    cd $path_dock$t
    .... 
done
```

Of course, this strategy is just an attempt and it doesn't work. 
Do you have any suggestion to pass a argument to cd command made in this way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion:

```
for t in $(seq 1 1000)
do
    tmp=path_dock${t}
    cd ${!tmp}
    .... 
done
```

Comment: Actually, it works. Thank you for the quick answer and thanks to the users of this forum...honestly, it works very well and it is very hard to find skilled people in this kind of social. Thank again.

Comment: @danilo, on SO you could give up-vote to people's helpful answers to thank them and select any one of the answer as correct answer too out of all, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I am trying to vote but... How can I do it?

Comment: @danilo, may be your reputation is less as of now, you could now try to select any of the answer as correct answer then when you have enough repo on SO then given up votes, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of many numbered variables

```
path_dock=()
for i in {1..100} ; do
    path_dock+=($(awk 'NR=='$i' {print $1}' input))
done
...
for i in {1..100} ; do
    cd "${path_dock[i]}"
    ...
done
```

Comment: 1) The `$i` is kind of useless inside single quotes 2) It would be better to call `awk` just once with a range then to call it `n` times 3) `set -f`

Comment: @mickp: Fixed 1)